# What is the reason that in git we can refer to HEAD by --?

Tags: git, git-checkout

We all know `git status` command, and beginning of its output:

```
$ git status
On branch add_multiple_items_to_set__to_master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

the last mentioned line suggest that we should use `--` to refer to last commit - `HEAD`.

I always wondered from where this come from. It took me a while to figured out, that I can use `git checkout HEAD <file>...` and expect this same result, and that `git log -1 --` and `git log -1 HEAD` also is this same.

In which statements `--` syntax are more natural? Are there any other multiple dashes shortcuts, like `---`, etc.?

Comment: it would be great to hear some feedback from people who keeps downvoting my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--` is not specific to Git, and it doesn't refer to `HEAD`.

It is a commonly used argument in Unixy command-line tools indicating the end of the options. Basically, it says "anything following me is a regular argument, not an option, even if it starts with `-` or `--`".

It's a way to let the tool operate on, say, a file called `--foo`:

```
git checkout --foo
# Um... I don't have an option called --foo. Time to bail out!

git checkout -- --foo
# Ooh, look! I'll operate on this perfectly valid file called --foo
```

Git just happens to default to using `HEAD` for many commands.

See also

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash
- https://serverfault.com/questions/114897/what-does-double-dash-mean-in-this-shell-command
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147745/12606

Answer (score 2):

`--` is just a separator which indicates that everything that comes after will be files.

So, when you are saying `git checkout -- <file>`
You are doing the command `git checkout` specifically for the specified files.
And when you do `git checkout` without specifying a branch/commit, the HEAD ref will be used as default.

So `git checkout -- <file>` is equivalent to `git checkout HEAD -- <file>` and the `--` is just a separator

Comment: is that right, that `--` is bash feature rather than git?

Comment: No, it't not a bash feature.  Your shell does not process command line arguments to commands.  It's just a standard behavior for programs that accept command line options.